# Mobilenet: Transfer learning with Gradcam

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, mobilenet

I am a newbie to all this so please be kind to this question :)

What I am trying to do is train a Mobilenet classifier using the transfer learning technique and then implement the Gradcam technique to understand what my model is looking into.

1. I created a model

> ```
> input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=IMG_SHAPE)
> x = preprocess_input(input_layer)
> y = base_model(x)
> y = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(y)
> y = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(y)
> outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(y)
> model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=outputs)
> model.summary()
> ```

**model summary:**

```
Model: "functional_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_RealDiv_1 (Tenso [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Sub_1 (TensorFlo [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
mobilenetv2_1.00_224 (Functi (None, 7, 7, 1280)        2257984   
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_1 ( (None, 1280)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 1280)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 6405      
=================================================================
Total params: 2,264,389
Trainable params: 6,405
Non-trainable params: 2,257,984
_________________________________________________________________
```

2. passed it to grad cam algorithm but the grad cam algorithm is not able to find the last convolutional layer

**Plausible solution:**
If instead of having an encapsulated 'mobilenetv2_1.00_224' layer if I can have unwrapped layers of mobilenet added in the model the grad cam algorithm will be able to find that last layer

**Problem**

I am not able to create the model where I can have data augmentation and pre_processing layer added to mobilenet unwrapped layers.

Thanks in advance

Regards
Ankit

Comment: I currently have exactly the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Skruff yes I was able to solve this have posted the snippet in below anser

Answer (score 0):

@skruff see if this helps

```
def make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, pred_index=None):
# First, we create a model that maps the input image to the activations
# of the last conv layer as well as the output predictions
grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
    [model.inputs], [model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output, model.output]
)

# Then, we compute the gradient of the top predicted class for our input image
# with respect to the activations of the last conv layer
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    last_conv_layer_output, preds = grad_model(img_array)
    if pred_index is None:
        pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
    class_channel = preds[:, pred_index]

# This is the gradient of the output neuron (top predicted or chosen)
# with regard to the output feature map of the last conv layer
grads = tape.gradient(class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)

# This is a vector where each entry is the mean intensity of the gradient
# over a specific feature map channel
pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))

# We multiply each channel in the feature map array
# by "how important this channel is" with regard to the top predicted class
# then sum all the channels to obtain the heatmap class activation
last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_output[0]
heatmap = last_conv_layer_output @ pooled_grads[..., tf.newaxis]
heatmap = tf.squeeze(heatmap)

# For visualization purpose, we will also normalize the heatmap between 0 & 1
heatmap = tf.maximum(heatmap, 0) / tf.math.reduce_max(heatmap)
return heatmap.numpy()
```